# GPS indoor precision

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, gps, indoor-positioning-system

I have a App that needs an accurate address by using the mobile phone GPS coordinates in PORTUGAL and BRAZIL.

When I try to get my current location address(indoors), the locality, as well as street name is correct but the street number and postal code is usually wrong.

I'm using reverse geocoding whith the google Maps API here is the call code:

```
  NSString *requestUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false", coordinatesString];
    //Creating the HTTP Request and setting the required post values
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestUrlString]];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:200];
    [request setDelegate:self];

    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(geocodeFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(geocodeFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

My question is, by using the IOS Maps framework, can I get the coordinates of a specific place and translate it to a correct address?
Also what can I do to increase the precision of the indoor/outdoor coordinates?

Thanks in Advance, for more clarification on the question just ask, I will be around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497), you can find all you need to do Forward/Reverse geocoding usig the [CoreLocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html) framework.

For the precision inside a building, you've not much to do; inside buildings you could get a bad [triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation), it really depends on what kind of building you are. If you're near a window probably you can get good coordinates, but if you're for example in the center of an airport it's difficult.

Comment: For precision inside buildings, there are some additions in iOS7 that should be considered and could prove useful. In particular, look at something called iBeacons.

Comment: @isaac Yep, i know, but we can't discuss here :)